# Command to Run (Eval) "Hello World" in ELISP on Eshell?

Tags: eshell, shell-command, load

I am new to Emacs and ELISP

A file `(message "Hello World")` saved as `hello.el`.
Now, how to **run** (evaluate) this file on  Eshell?

```
~/Documents $ ....... hello.el
```

Comment: How about `(load "/path/to/hello.el")`

Comment: Yes, it shows that successfully loaded by displaying 't'.
Now, how to get it display the message "Hello World"?

~/Documents $ (load "~/Documents/hello.el")
t
~/Documents $

Comment: If you are looking at writing elisp look at ielm and eval-region

Comment: I successfully did evaluation at direct buffer, ielm, and windows shell. Somehow, I feel very comfortable with Eshell. I was able to make it smoothly for Python, C, and C++ on Eshell, but when it came to ELISP, it was not working, and nowhere in google I could find a way out.

Comment: @Tom I guess you did just not see the message after the load. Check the *Messages* buffer. Hint: C-h e.

Comment: Nothing appears in the buffer. Sir, I just requested what is that ONE-WORD command to be filled on the DOTTED place.

Comment: Just as an aside, it is very rare to run elisp programs from a shell in this manner.  You almost certainly will want to run them interactively in the manner @eflanigan00 mentions.

Answer (score 4):

The one word you request can also be just a dot `.`.

After running that command you get:

```
~/Documents $ . hello.el
Hello World
~/Documents $
```

If this is too strange for you you can also use:

```
~/Documents $ eshell-source-file hello.el
Hello World
~/Documents $
```

Why that works:
The dot runs the `eshell/\.` command which in turn runs `eshell-source-file`.
The current eshell sources the file `hello.el`, i.e., it interprets its contents as eshell-commands.

Since `message` returns the generated message as string and `eshell` prints the return values of the executed commands you get "Hello World" printed out in the eshell buffer.

**Note** that this is not the same as `load`ing `hello.el`! The content of `hello.el` is not interpreted as sequence of elisp forms but as sequence of eshell-commands! `eshell` just happens to understand elisp forms.
Be aware that the comment character of eshell is the hash-sign `#` and not the semi-colon `;` as for elisp!

Because of the difference in the comment syntax this method will fail for most elisp-files.
Your example file `hello.el` is both - a valid elisp file *and* a valid eshell file.

---

Note: I wrote this as a separate answer since it is a completely different approach (no elisp but eshell interpretation).

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> A file (message "Hello World") saved as 'hello.el'.
>   Now, how to run (evaluate) this file on Eshell?
>   `~/Documents $ ....... hello.el`

I just fill in the command at the dots:

```
~/Documents $ load hello.el
t
~/Documents $
```

The reply `t` of the `load` command says that the file was loaded successfully Type <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `load` <kbd>RET</kbd> to obtain a more detailed description for the `load` command.

You find the actual message `Hello World` in the `*Messages*` buffer.

---

Note that there are many ways to execute elisp code.
I list some of them:

- If you just want to test a single elisp form you can type <kbd>M-:</kbd> input the lisp form in the minibuffer and press <kbd>RET</kbd>. The output is shown as message in the `*Messages*` buffer and in the view-area (i.e., the inactive minibuffer).
- If you want to test small snippets of elisp you can use the `*scratch*` buffer. [`lisp-interaction` mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Interaction.html) is active in `*scratch*`. You can input your form and press <kbd>C-j</kbd> right behind it. The form is evaluated with `eval-print-last-sexp` and the result is printed in `*scratch*` at the point where you pressed <kbd>C-j</kbd>. If you place point in the form and press <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-C-x</kbd> the lisp form is instrumented for edebug and evaluated. That shows you what is going on step-by-step.
- If your example `hello.el` actually stands for a fully fledged library which you want to test and if this library is in `load-path` you can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-library` <kbd>RET</kbd>, input the name of the library, and press <kbd>RET</kbd>. This loads (i.e., executes) the library.
- If you need to work on the library you can also open the library file. Emacs activates `emacs-lisp` mode for the file buffer. If you visit that buffer there is a menu item `Emacs-Lisp` in the menu bar where you find `Evaluate Buffer`. Sometimes it is easier to use the `find-library` command (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd>) to open a library instead of `find-file` (the usual <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>). Another important item of the `Emacs-Lisp` menu is `Instrument Function for Debugging`.
- User [eflanigan00](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/13934/eflanigan00) already mentioned [`ielm` -- an interactive emacs-lisp repl](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/IELM) where you can input your lisp forms and get emacs' answer as response in the same buffer.
- The `babel` package from `org-mode` offers an interesting way for literate programming. There you can write your documentation and embed the corresponding lisp snippets in [source code blocks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Working-With-Source-Code.html). These lisp snippets can be evaluated by <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on the header lines of the source blocks.

Comment: I get the following reply:           

~/Documents/Code/El $ load hello.el            

Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, hello.el

Comment: @Tom If the file `hello.el` exists in the current directory the error message indicates that `nil` is not in `load-path`. The name of the current directory is printed with `pwd`. The content of the current directory is listed with `ls`. You can inspect `load-path` with `echo $load-path`. `nil` in `load-path` stands for the current  directory. You can add `nil` to `load-path` with ``add-to-list `load-path `nil`` or with `(add-to-list 'load-path nil)`.

Comment: Wow! Sir, this is way too much for a beginner like me!! I appreciate your very comprehensive reply. Let me try...

Comment: @Tom Did the receipt in my last comment help you to get `load hello.el` working from the `eshell`-prompt? Note, `eshell` is a good shell. Its primary goal is to provide you with a shell that only depends on emacs but not directly on the platform. Elisp evaluation in the eshell is possible and it helps to get more complicated shell-jobs done with `eshell` but `eshell` is not intended to be a lisp-repl.

Comment: Sir, I just requested what is that ONE-WORD command to be filled on the DOTTED place.

Comment: @Tom Okay, the text over the separating line tells you what that word is _and what it does_.  (Maybe, you are expecting the wrong action.) The part below that line is supplemental.

Answer (score 2):

To run program written in Emacs Lisp from shell like other general languages, use [(elisp) Batch Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Batch-Mode.html):

```
~ $ cat ~/Documents/hello.el 
(message "Hello World")
~ $ emacs --batch --load ~/Documents/hello.el
Hello World
~ $
```

However, it is just much easier to run Emacs Lisp code within Emacs, see [(emacs) Lisp Eval](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html). since Emacs is the IDE of Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score -1):

This worked:

```
~/Documents $ eval-buffer hello.el

Hello World
```

Comment: This only works if the file `hello.el` is already opened in some buffer. Otherwise you get the answer `No such buffer`. If you want to stick to `eval-buffer` and `hello.el` is not open yet you need something like `find-file-noselect hello.el; eval-buffer hello.el`. Furthermore, I am almost sure that you did not try very hard to follow the other answers. Note, I did not down-vote your answer and I am very much against down-voting without commenting why.

Comment: @Tobias You are RIGHT! I Checked your answer as the correct one. But it says that I am too new. What to do?