# How to do 'Hello World' in Emacs-LISP on Eshell and display evaluation in shell area itself, instead of echo area or *message* Buffer?

Tags: eshell, print

I am new to Emacs and struggling to learn it.

How to get rid of the line **Emacs: command not found**?

```
   ~/Documents $ eshell-source-file hello.el
   Emacs: command not found
   Hello World
   ~/Documents $
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html

Comment: You tagged the question with `eshell`, but your question says nothing about eshell. Show or describe the relevant parts of your init ifile.

Comment: Echo-area messages are generally logged in buffer `*Messages*`. You should look there to see them: `C-x b *Messages*`.

Comment: DoMiNeLa10: Sir, this manual is confusing to me since I am a beginner.

Comment: Drew: Sir, The shell I specified (code above) is eshell. Because, I prefer and like Eshell. I believe, for issue of eshell to work, there should be some customization in .init.el. Please advise me if I am wrong.

Comment: Drew: Sir, Buffer > messages is working. But, I wish to see if eshell area also work.

Comment: For me, part of learning Emacs has improving my skill in regarding reading the manuals and developing the habit of reading them. I've been at it for several years and think I am getting better, but I still have a long way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34239/command-to-run-eval-hello-world-in-elisp-on-eshell#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command to Run (Eval) "Hello World" in ELISP on Eshell?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34239/command-to-run-eval-hello-world-in-elisp-on-eshell)

Comment: Please don't edit questions to ask something different.

Comment: ;; Comment is creating problem. So how to comment a file to evaluate in eshell? Shall I ask it as a different question?

Comment: First, this question should be reverted back to the original so that the answers make sense. If there is are several questions, it is safe to post each individually. For a question regarding `hello.el` it probably makes sense to include the source code in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put (just) this in "hello.el":

```
(prin1 "Hello, world!")
```

Then from the eshell prompt:

```
~/temp $ eshell-source-file "hello.el"
Hello, world!
~/temp $
```

I may be misunderstanding your general intent but from your questions, it seems as though you're trying to "run programs" the way you would run C programs - write a source file hello.c, compile it, run it at the command line, it prints "Hello, world!" and exits, and you get a command prompt again. If you're trying to learn elisp using ielm or eshell, you're working with an interpreter (REPL) - programs are built interactively. So if you want to print "Hello world!" you don't need to make a separate source file; just do this:

```
~/temp $ (prin1 "hello, world!")
hello, world!
```

But you can also define functions, apply them, and so on:

```
~/temp $ (defun f (x) (* x x))
f
~/temp $ (f 17)
289
~/temp $
```

You don't need to build a separate source file just to load it into eshell: Just build your program line-by-line in eshell or ielm.

As other people have suggested, in emacs, do C-h-i to bring up info, and check out the documentation there. Good luck!

Comment: **@bikenaga, Thank you, Great answer!**

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

1. `eshell` can be configured to route specific commands (and subcommands) to the regular terminal. See the documentation for [visual commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Input_002fOutput). Whether or not this is worth the trouble, depends on how much getting a tool to perform in a way it was not really designed to perform is worth.
2. A good tool for interactive sessions with elisp is `interactive elisp mode` which is invoked using `M-x ielm`. It provides a full elisp REPL. Files can be loaded using `(load name-of-file)`.
3. The `*scratch*` buffer (or any other elisp buffer) is another way of working with elisp files interactively. Using `eval-print-last-sexp` will print the results of the `sexp` directly in the buffer. Like any Emacs function `eval-print-last-sexp` can have any keybinding the user wishes assigned.

Comment: Hello Ben: I tried all the 3 options: (1) Being a total new person, it is too heavy for me. (2) it is not working (3) (a) It prints the result directly to buffer area, (b) Prints the last message call only. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @user16438 In what ways is `ielm` not working? I can see why configuring eshell using visual commands is to heavy for a new user because `eshell` is not really designed to do what you are trying to do anyway. For me, part of being a new user has been learning new ways of doing things and usually those new ways of doing things is not the way "I want". For me, wanting to do things in a 'bad' or 'wrong' way is part of being a new user. As I said, I've spent years learning Emacs and all that learning has been learning to do things in new ways.

Comment: Method (2): I did: `M-x ielm`  It took to ELISP>  Then I entered **ELISP>** `load hello.el`  it displays  `*** IELM error ***  More than one sexp in input`

Comment: @user16438 *ielm* requires elisp code. So the it needs to be `(load "hello.el")` or a more precise path if the file hello.el is not in the current working directory. For example, entering `(+ 3 4)` at the *ielm* prompt will return the value `7`. For what it is worth, my favorite elisp tutorial is http://dantorop.info/project/emacs-animation/ and I recommend working through a few tutorials because it is worth the effort for a tool that will be used for many years.

Comment: @user16438 see this question for a more direct solution https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34239/command-to-run-eval-hello-world-in-elisp-on-eshell#

Comment: This works!!! but there is a small issue. it prints like this: **Emacs: command not found**
Hello World
How can I get rid of the first line?

Comment: @user16438 I don't know what you mean by 'this works'.

Comment: It prints:
`~/Documents $ eshell-source-file hello.el`       
**Emacs: command not found**      
Hello World!  
`~/Documents $`   
How can I get rid of the first line **Emacs: command not found**?

Comment: @user16438 I suspect that your source code in `hello.el` might not be valid elisp. Again, I suggest working through tutorials and/or reading the manuals.